# want to customize/extend wicked-charts legend item click event

Tags: highcharts, wicket, wicket-1.6

I have implemented a wicked-chart which shows 4 series in the legend. Now I want to handle the series click event in legend and update some values outside the wicked highchart.
To be specific, I want to implement exactly like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/)  but in java wicked-chart.

```
plotOptions: 
     {    
        series: {    
            events: {    
               legendItemClick: function(event) {    
                   //Do something here    
                   return false;    
                    }    
                }
```

I did search all the methods of PlotOptions class but could get something similar to highcharts legendItemClick event.

Comment: always is an option use the the jQuery plugin directly

Comment: Have you tried to use java wrappers? http://www.highcharts.com/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was not to find alternative for legendItemClick in wicket-charts as they do not have one. Instead I did this:

In your page html, give id="chart". Doing this highcharts shall fix your id to "chartVar" instead of changing it at each run.

```
 <div wicket:id="chart" id="chart"></div>
```

In your javascript, define your series click using .highcharts-legend-item as below.

```
 var onSeriesClick = function() {
    var that = this;
    for (var i=0;i<chartVar.series.length;i++)
    {
        $(".highcharts-legend-item:contains(" + chartVar.series[i].name + ")").click(function(){
            // your legend click logic goes here                    
        });
    }
}
```